# Setting up Grav as a subdirectory on existing website

Tags: apache, cms

I followed the instructions from [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-grav-cms-on-ubuntu-1804-lts/) (part 4 only) for setting up Grav.

I already have an existing website which is at `var/www/html` on my web server, and the home page is an html file called `index.html` which sits in that folder. I set this up by installing LAMP on the server.

What I want is to just have a link on my home page] which says **Blog** and then links to the stuff that I make in Grav. How can I achieve this? If this is a silly way of doing things (which I imagine it might be), then please let me know how could I achieve this differently.

TL;DR - how can I set up Grav as a subdirectory on my existing website?

Comment: Do you want grav on a subdirectory, subdomain, or separate domain name?

Comment: Either a subdirectory or a subdomain would be fine, though I would prefere a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder within the `/www/html` directory called `/blog` (`/www/html/blog`) then install Grav to that directory. the web server works just like a normal folder structure in Windows/macOS.